# Get the lat and lng sometime is NULL with google map api json

Tags: java, json, google-maps

When lots of address be transformed to lat&lng by following code, sometimes the result is null.
I think that reason is using this url too much, so getting null value.
how do I solve this problem to get correct lat&lng?

```
String transformerUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&language=zh-TW&sensor=false&region=tw";

private String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public String[] getLocationInfoByAddress(String address)
        throws IOException, JSONException {

    String[] latLngStr = new String[2];

    String encodeAddress = URLEncoder.encode(address, "Utf-8");
    String formatAddress = String.format(transformerUrl, encodeAddress);
    InputStream is = new URL(formatAddress).openConnection().getInputStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        //System.out.println(jsonText);

        try {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONObject(jsonText)
                    .getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); ++i) {
                if (arr.getJSONObject(i).get("geometry") != null) {
                    Object lat =  arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lat");
                    Object lng =  arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lng") ;

                    latLngStr[0] = lat.toString();
                    latLngStr[1] = lng.toString();

                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }


    } finally {
        is.close();
    }

    return latLngStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the returned [Status](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes) before using the result.

The Google Maps Geocoding Web Service is subject to a quota and a rate limit.  If you don't comply to those, you will get a status of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

If you aren't including a [key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) in your URL (which I don't see in your question), adding a key to your request may allow you your own independent quota (only really applicable if you are on a shared server).

If that doesn't help, you need to throttle your requests to comply with quota/rate limit.  There are questions on how to do that on StackOverflow.

Comment: i got this "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT". so any solution to solve it? thank you in advance.

Comment: thank you ! I will search something about throttle requests. I think this a cool way.